# How can I get text/html from a web page I currently have open in a browser on my machine?

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I want to do something like this:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://a-website.com/')
```

But instead of passing a defined hard-coded url, I would like to get the page that I currently have open in my web browser. ie `page = requests.get(whateverisopeninmychrome)`. For what it's worth, its the text contents of a div that I am specifically looking for.

Is there any way to do this or is it even possible? I could not find any other information about pulling the html/contents from a browser that is currently open on your machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't like this. One way is to open **Developer Console** on **Google Chrome** or **Firefox** with your website open and use javascript syntax like this:

For searching by **className**, it will return a list and you will have to get one element:

```
var html = document.getElementsByClassName('htmlClassHere')[0].innerText
```

For searching by **id**, it will return the element and you can use it like this:

```
var html = document.getElementsById('htmlIdHere').innerText
```